# Dynamically enable/disable VF inputfield1 based on selected picklist value of field2

Tags: apex

I have a requirement, where I have to make custom field enable and disable on the basis of a chosen value of a Picklist field.

I have Picklist field `Pricing_Option__c` which has 3 values : Lowest Doscount, Specific Discount, and Highest Discount.

There is another field : Specific_Discount__c (Datatype Percent)

My requirement is : `Specific_Discount__c` will always be disabled, unless Pricing_Option__c = "Specific Discount"

What I have done :

I can make the `Specific_Discount__c` field enable and disable based on value of Pricing_Option__c.

But I want `Specific_Discount__c` would be enabled and  disabled as soon as we change the picklist value,

Is there something we can do with `<apex:inputField />` `onChange` attribute

Answer (score 3):

Refer this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32721/show-hide-required-field-based-on-picklist-value-issues) that explains how to show/hide a field based on picklist modification. You can make some changes to change the behaviour to enable/ disable instead of show/hide.

Use the

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="xxx"  />
```

Make sure to chose the rRender scope/ actionRegion correctly so that it includes the custom field that you want to disable.